# Permission denied in creating a database in ASP MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to store a session state into SQL Server using the following command in order to generate the database :

> aspnet_regsql.exe -S localhost -E -ssadd -sstype p

but I recieve an error  which mention that the permission is denied in database 'master' :

> SQL Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE
>   DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

Comment: What user you're using to connect with SQL Server DB? I think your current user doesn't have sufficent privilege to execute `CREATE TABLE` DDL statement, try using `sa` or other user with full control privileges.

Comment: I tried but it still don't working with the same error

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto He is NOT trying to create a table

Comment: @sepupic It's just a typo, I mean `CREATE DATABASE` statement there. To create a database the SQL Server user must have sufficent privilege level since it's also a DDL command too.

Answer (score 0):

Your application tries to `CREATE DATABASE` in some way.

It can be `RESTORE DATABASE` or `sp_attach` or explicit `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

It can be even parameter in connection string that indicates database to be attached.

You can use SQL Server `Profiler` to see the exact code that cause this error.
You should find what login tries to execute this code and grant him `CREATE ANY DATABASE` permission or include him to `sysadmin` role